# Cannot start service couchdb: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint

Tags: docker, couchdb

I am getting this error when I try to run:

```
docker-compose -f planet.yml -p planet up -d --build
```

Starting 06549b64d3ef_planet_couchdb_1 ... error

ERROR: for 06549b64d3ef_planet_couchdb_1  Cannot start service couchdb: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 06549b64d3ef_planet_couchdb_1 (c3c0c1ed7afe24c6f78fbffb7f1ed087b0e501fac06ace8b6e9c6244edc95c27): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:2200 failed: port is already allocated'

ERROR: for couchdb  Cannot start service couchdb: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 06549b64d3ef_planet_couchdb_1 (c3c0c1ed7afe24c6f78fbffb7f1ed087b0e501fac06ace8b6e9c6244edc95c27): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:2200 failed: port is already allocated'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Answer (score 0):

The error message spells out the problem.

```
Bind for 0.0.0.0:2200 failed: port is already allocated
```

You have something already bound on port `2200`, and you're trying to bind the `couchdb` service in `planet.yml` to the same port.